# MySQL write performance after truncate & optimize

Tags: mysql, innodb, rdbms, dbms

Once a year we truncate a table of  several GBs and millions of rows and then run optimize in order to shrink the size of the corresponding ibd file on the file system.

However, as this is write intensive table, we are wondering whether running optimize is actually a good idea. Maybe it’s smarter to leave the file size as is and let MySQL reuse already allocated disk space.

Is it more efficient in terms of write performance to optimize the table in order to shrink the file size and then let it progressively grow again, or just reuse space previously allocated?

We use InnoDB as storage engine and MySQL 5.7 as DBMS.

Comment: This entirely depends on the nature of your workload, which is not known to anyone but you. The question can only be answered by testing the two approaches and comparing monitoring results.

Comment: I don't understand -- `TRUNCATE TABLE` throws all the data away and leaves you will an empty table that take very little space.  No need to `OPTIMIZE` at that point.

Comment: @mustaccio sure, we think that asking the community could be helpful as other people may have had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` throws away the table and creates a new, empty table, with the same schema.  There is nothing left to `OPTIMIZE`.

If you are really throwing away the data, why did you keep it?  Or, maybe you would prefer to toss the "oldest" part of the data each week?  And do it with virtually no impact on writes?  If so, you have a classic case for `PARTITIONing`.  Use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and a weekly task to `DROP` the  oldest partition and deal with making a new partition.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Be sure to have `innodb_file_per_table=ON`.

(If this does not address your Question, please elaborate on it.)

Comment: Hi @Rick James, actually from my experience, I can tell that TRUNCATE TABLE doesn’t actually shrink the ibd file, it just deletes all rows but the disk space previously allocated remains allocated, it is not claimed by the OS. Based on that, we were wondering whether working on a large file can decrease MySQL performance or not.

Comment: @pAkY88 - Which OS?  Did you check the file size after a few minutes?  Some filesystems are slow to record the releasing of blocks to the OS.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS